# Where to initialise data in Angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm finding my way with my first Angular app, and one of the services (used to generate SQL query strings) needs to be initialised with a schema declared in its `constant` block. At the moment the schema / configuration isn't finalised, so I'm doing a bit of processing, and the result is then made available to a private variable inside the service.

I'd like a bit of guidance as to best practice when doing this. It looks like there are 3 options.

**1) Expose a public `init` function on the factory and call it from elsewhere**

This is a possibility, but I don't want to have to fire up the factory from elsewhere (it will be the first thing that loads).

**2) Use an IIFE in the body of the factory**

This may well be smelly but it actually works fine.

```
angular.module('dataService', [])

.constant('DB_CONFIG', {
  // ...data used to bootstrap the service
})

.factory('sqlQueries', 
  ['DB_CONFIG',
  function(){

    var privateStuff_;

    (function(){
       // do processing work on DB_CONFIG in here
       privateStuff_ = result;
    })();

    return {
      // no init function needed!
      publicMethod1: publicMethod1
    }
  }
])
```

**3) Use the `run` block**

I'm confused about Angular's `run` blocks to be honest. Presumably any variables declared in here will be available to ANY factory on that module? This isn't clear. I could move all code into a run block but can't really see the benefit.

Can anyone could clarify the best practice here?

Comment: I would use 2. Why does it have to be an iife block?

Comment: You should look at `provider` recipe of creating Angular service. That can do some initialization at `config` stage.

Comment: @PeterAshwell I was playing with this late last night and used an IIFE due to a misconception about firing order when reading the Angular API docs. Thought that it would be available even before the .config and .run blocks were fired...my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to initialize a service is the config block - that's what they're for.  There are 5 kinds of services:

1. Factory
2. Service
3. Provider
4. Value
5. Constant

In order to setup your service so that it can be injected and initialized in your config block you should implement a "Provider".

Example:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.provider('dataService', function() {
    var privateStuff_;
    this.init = function(db_config) {
         // do processing work on DB_CONFIG in here
         privateStuff_ = result;
    }
    function publicMethod1() {
        ...
    }
    this.$get = function() {
       return {
           publicMethod1: publicMethod1
       }
    }
});
```

Setup your DB_CONFIG as a constant (otherwise, it cannot be injected into your config block):

```
app.constant('DB_CONFIG', {
    ...
});
```

Then in your config block, inject the provider, and configure it with DB_CONFIG:

```
app.config(function(dataServiceProvider, DB_CONFIG) {
     dataServiceProvider.init(DB_CONFIG);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this...I'm still not clear though. I was of the understanding that `factory` is a convenience wrapper for `provider`, is this correct? If that's the case what benefits does the above pattern give me that is different from the code in my example (I used a `.constant` block there)? Is it that the provider can be injected into a `config` block  whereas a factory cannot? Some clarification on this would be really helpful. You are still exposing a public `init` method, and this is then fired in the main app module...presumably this is Angular the way to do it?

Comment: You are correct - factories cannot be injected into a config block. Providers allow you to configure the service, before it is cached and injected into, say, for example, a controller function. The main benefit is clarity, and testability. No, init is not publically exposed from the service because the injectable is the return value from the $get function - not the provider itself.

Comment: <lightbulb> Thanks for the clear explanation. Those API docs will make more sense now!